# WSUS error updates on some computers

Tags: wsus

Hy everybody !

I have a problem with my WSUS server. A error appear showing that is install only at 99% some updates on computers (see my attachment).

It is possible do refresh and install this updates ?

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Did you look to see what update has failed?

Answer (score 0):

Your picture is lacking some details but you can try the following steps in an administrative command prompt

```
net stop wuauserv

reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate /v ElevateNonAdmins /f
reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate /v TargetGroup /f
reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate /v TargetGroupEnabled /f
reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate /v WUServer /f
reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate /v WUStatusServer /f

reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate /v SusClientId /f

rmdir /S /Q C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution

net start wuauserv

gpupdate /force

wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /downloadnow /detectnow
wuauclt.exe /reportnow
```